# Is including stdarg.h necessary for "..." argument in header files?

Tags: c, arguments, header-files, variadic-functions

```
#ifndef WHATEVER_H
#define WHATEVER_H

void test(const char *format, ...); // would you have to #include <stdarg.h> for ... on argument, or is it ok if you don't use it

#endif // WHATEVER_H
```

So if I were to have a header file like this, where I needed to put `...` as my argument for my `void test` function, would I have to include stdarg.h for the `...` argument, or is it not mandatory?

Comment: Headers are needed for declarations of types/functions/objects. `...` is neither, it is a syntax element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The header does not need to include `<stdarg.h>` if the prototypes only include the ellipsis (`, ...`) notation.  The code implementing the `test()` function will need to include `<stdarg.h>`, but the header declaring it need not.

However, you should often consider creating a second function, `void vtest(const char *format, va_list args);` to match the `test()` function in the header, and then you do need `<stdarg.h>` to define the `va_list` type (and the implementation code no longer needs a separate `#include <stdarg.h>`).  With the `vtest()` declaration in the header, the implementation of the `test()` function becomes trivial:

```c
void test(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vtest(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

This is particularly simple since there is no return value to relay, but returning a value is not very much harder.  It's often a good idea to implement a variadic function like `test()` using this scheme, even if you don't expose the `vtest()` function — it is rather likely that you'll want the extra flexibility it provides eventually.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to, but it will rather hard to access parameters hidden behind the `...` without macros from this header.

you will need to know your implementation for example for gcc you can use:

```
__builtin_va_start(v,l)
__builtin_va_end(v)
__builtin_va_arg(v,l)
__builtin_va_copy(d,s)
```