# Variadic function is behaving strangely

Tags: c, function, arguments, variadic

I am trying to understand what is wrong with my variadic function.
For some reason it breaks all the variadic arguments, except the second and the third.

The function looks correct according to the documentation:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic

I am using C standard 17, which is lower than 23.

Here is the C standard in CMake settings.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(3 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
```

The minimal working test, which shows the strangeness.

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    printf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    test("%d %d %d %d %d\n", (unsigned char) (1), (unsigned char) (2), (unsigned char) (3), (unsigned char) (4), (unsigned char) (5));
    return 0;
}
```

OS is Windows 10.
IDE is JetBrains CLion 2023.1.1.
Toolchain is selected as Visual Studio.
Compiler is Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.35.32216.1 for x64.
Architecture is 64-bit x86.

I see the following output of the test code:

```
1897200872 2 3 1 1077874749
```

So, only two arguments of five are correct. Other arguments are broken.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

OK. I have changed the `printf` to `vprintf` and now it prints the values correctly. But a new strangeness happens.

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *smprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    len++;
    char *buf = malloc(len);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, len, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    return buf;
}

void test(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    //vprintf(fmt, args);
    vprintf("Result: %s.\n", smprintf(fmt, args));
    va_end (args);
    //free(x);
}

int main() {
    test("%d %d %d %d %d\n", (unsigned char) (1), (unsigned char) (2), (unsigned char) (3), (unsigned char) (4), (unsigned char) (5));
    return 0;
}
```

Here, in the `smprintf` function, I am trying to make a formatted C string from the format and arguments.

Now the `smprintf` function breaks all the parameters for some reason.

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: You want `vprintf`, not `printf`.

Comment: Thank you. I have added another function to receive the variadic arguments, to show what happens next.

Comment: Your function needs to accept a `va_list`.  You'll also need to use `va_copy` if you want to use it more than once.

Comment: Make sure you're aware of the *default argument promotions*, which always happen in variable-length argument lists.  So those unsigned chars you're passing are actually going to be passed as unsigned ints.

Comment: See also [Repeated use of a variadic function argument doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9309246/15169) and [Is including `<stdrg.h> necessary for `...` argument in header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64035651/15168)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated working solution.

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *smprintf(const char *fmt, va_list args) {
    va_list args3;
    va_copy(args3, args);
    int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args3);
            va_end (args3);
    len++;
    char *buf = malloc(len);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    vsnprintf(buf, len, fmt, args);
    return buf;
}

void test(const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
            va_start(args, fmt);
    va_list args2;
    va_copy(args2, args);
    vprintf(fmt, args); // Debug.
    printf("\n"); // Debug.
            va_end (args);
    char *x = smprintf(fmt, args2);
    printf("Result: %s.\n", x);
    free(x);
            va_end (args2);
}

int main() {
    test("%d %d %d %d %d", (unsigned char) (1), (unsigned char) (2), (unsigned char) (3), (unsigned char) (4), (unsigned char) (5));
    return 0;
}
```

I am now able to create a formatted C string from the format and variadic arguments.

Comment: This is still wrong. After you pass `args` to `vsnprintf` it is incorrect to use it again. You need to use `va_copy` *inside* smprintf.

Comment: I pass a copy of args to the `smprintf`. It works. Why is it wrong ?

Comment: It may work today, on your computer, but it is not _guaranteed_ to work. The copy outside smprintf is also necessary (but only because of the lines marked "debug") but doesn't affect the fact that you call `snprintf` twice on the same va_list object, inside smprintf.

Comment: I have updated the code. Is it good now ?

Comment: You're still being sloppy with `va_end` -- every call to `va_copy` must also be paired with a `va_end` -- but this is harmless; I'm not aware of _any_ ABI in which `va_end` actually does something. Precisely correct code would look like this: https://godbolt.org/z/6G53vGen4

Comment: I have understood the mistake and edited the code. Is it now good ? Thank you.